# Using join with conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have below two queries which are giving the results

```
select order.ORDER_NUMBER,
       upc.PROD_ID,
       shipmentItem.upc_id,
       order.ORDER_DATE
  from shipment shipment,
 Order order, shipment_item shipmentItem, UPC upc
 where order.ORDER_DATE > current timestamp - 24
 months
   and order.order_number = shipment.order_number
   and shipmentItem.SHIPMENT_ID = shipment.SHIPMENT_ID
   and order.user_id = '123456'
   and upc.UPC_ID = shipmentItem.UPC_ID
 order by order.ORDER_DATE desc
```

which gives the below output

```
 Order_number prod_id  upc_id     order_date

    1234507  6489785  38890630  2018-05-27 13:12:47.564791
    1234504  1310     10855     2018-05-27 13:10:41.475177
    1234504  448832   23431431  2018-05-27 13:10:41.475177
```

And another query with conditional aggregation as

```
select upc_id,
       max(case
             when attr_name = 'COLOR_NORMAL' then
              attr_value
           end) as color,
       max(case
             when attr_name = 'SIZE' then
              attr_value
           end) as size
  from Unary_Upc
 where UPC_ID in (38890630, 10855, 23431431)
 group by UPC_ID;
```

which gives the below output

```
upc_id      color   size

10855       (null)  (null)
23431431    White   (null)
38890630    Black    8
```

How to join the two above queries such that the output comes as below?

```
   Order_number prod_id  upc_id    color    size   order_date

    1234507     6489785  38890630   Black   8       2018-05-27 13:12:47.564791
    1234504     1310     10855      (null)  (null)  2018-05-27 13:10:41.475177
    1234504     448832   23431431   White   (null)  2018-05-27 13:10:41.475177
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two correlated subqueries with removed `group by upc_id` against `ORA-01422` exception, and write your query due to `ANSI-92` format with aliases rather than full table names. By the way

- `order` is a reserved keyword, therefore it's not possible to create
  a table named `order` in Oracle, but the name `"order"` is possible.
- replace `current timestamp - 24 months` with `current_timestamp - interval '24' month`

  ```
  select o.order_number, u.prod_id, si.upc_id,       
        (select max(case
                when attr_name = 'COLOR_NORMAL' then
                  attr_value
                end)
           from Unary_Upc
          where upc_id = u.upc_id
         ) as color,
        (select max(case
                when attr_name = 'SIZE' then
                    attr_value
                end) 
           from Unary_Upc
          where upc_id = u.upc_id
         ) as size,              
         o.order_date
    from shipment s
    join "order" o on o.order_number = s.order_number
    join shipment_item si on si.shipment_id = s.shipment_id
    join upc u on u.upc_id = si.upc_id
   where order.order_date > current_timestamp  - interval '24' month
     and o.user_id = '123456'
   order by o.order_date desc
  ```

Comment: Thanks Barbaros, the  query worked with some minor edits.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by two methods:

**---Method 1 ---**

Join two subqueries as following:

```
SELECT
    A.ORDER_NUMBER,
    A.PROD_ID,
    A.UPC_ID,
    B.COLOR,
    B.SIZE,
    A.ORDER_DATE
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER,
            UPC.PROD_ID,
            SHIPMENTITEM.UPC_ID,
            ORDER.ORDER_DATE
        FROM
            SHIPMENT SHIPMENT,
            ORDER ORDER,
            SHIPMENT_ITEM SHIPMENTITEM,
            UPC UPC
        WHERE
            ORDER.ORDER_DATE > CURRENT timestamp - 24 months 
            AND ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER = SHIPMENT.ORDER_NUMBER
            AND SHIPMENTITEM.SHIPMENT_ID = SHIPMENT.SHIPMENT_ID
            AND ORDER.USER_ID = '123456'
            AND UPC.UPC_ID = SHIPMENTITEM.UPC_ID
    ) A
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            UPC_ID,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'COLOR_NORMAL' THEN ATTR_VALUE
            END) AS COLOR,
            MAX(CASE
                WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'SIZE' THEN ATTR_VALUE
            END) AS SIZE
        FROM
            UNARY_UPC_ATTR_VAL
        WHERE
            UPC_ID IN (
                38890630,
                10855,
                23431431
            )
        GROUP BY
            UPC_ID
    ) B ON ( A.UPC_ID = B.UPC_ID )
ORDER BY
    A.ORDER_DATE DESC WITH UR
```

### --

**---Method 2 ---**

Use `UNARY_UPC_ATTR_VAL` table in the first query and do `GROUP BY` as following:

```
SELECT
    ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER,
    UPC.PROD_ID,
    SHIPMENTITEM.UPC_ID,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'COLOR_NORMAL' THEN ATTR_VALUE
    END) AS COLOR,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN ATTR_NAME = 'SIZE' THEN ATTR_VALUE
    END) AS SIZE,
    ORDER.ORDER_DATE
FROM
    SHIPMENT SHIPMENT,
    ORDER ORDER,
    SHIPMENT_ITEM SHIPMENTITEM,
    UPC UPC,
    UNARY_UPC_ATTR_VAL UUAV -- ADDED THIS TABLE HERE
WHERE 
    order.ORDER_DATE >current timestamp - 24 months  
    AND ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER = SHIPMENT.ORDER_NUMBER
    AND SHIPMENTITEM.SHIPMENT_ID = SHIPMENT.SHIPMENT_ID
    AND ORDER.USER_ID = '123456'
    AND UPC.UPC_ID = SHIPMENTITEM.UPC_ID
    -- ADDED FOLLOWING CONDITION AND JOIN HERE
    AND UUAV.UPC_ID IN (
        38890630,
        10855,
        23431431
    )
    AND UUAV.UPC_ID = UPC.UPC_ID
    -- ADDED FOLLOWING GROUP BY
GROUP BY
    ORDER.ORDER_NUMBER,
    UPC.PROD_ID,
    SHIPMENTITEM.UPC_ID,
    ORDER.ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY
    ORDER.ORDER_DATE DESC WITH UR
```

Hope, This will help you.

Cheers!!